# Plugins for Zend_Mail

Tags: php, email, zend-mail

Does anyone know of any email providers (such as MailChimp) that provides plugins for Zend_Mail?

Ideally I just want to configure Zend_Mail to use such a provider rather than rewrite all occasions where Zend_Mail is called?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution will be own Zend_Mail_Transport class and setting it for example in bootstrap as default transport for Zend_Mail

```
$tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_MyTransport();
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($tr);
```